# Loading JavaScript library from CDN works, from local file doesn't

Tags: javascript

I have a problem where loading a JavaScript library via CDN works, but serving it from my own server with bower doesn't. The following is a minimal example of what is happening (just a HTML file that can be opened directly):

## Loading system@0.16.11.js from a CDN

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.11.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>    
</html>
```

If I open the Firefox Web Console and enter `System`, I get:

```js
System
Object { normalize: f/e.normalize(), locate: m/e.locate(), fetch: c/e.fetch(), translate: d/e.translate(), instantiate: d/e.instantiate(), _loader: Object, baseURL: "file:///…", paths: Object, originalSystem: Object, noConflict: $__global.upgradeSystemLoader/p.noConflict(), 17 more… }
```

## Loading system@0.16.11.js from a local directory

Then I downloaded [the JavaScript file](https://jspm.io/system@0.16.11.js) into the same directory as the HTML file and modified it to:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="system@0.16.11.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>    
</html>
```

If I enter `System` in the console now, I get:

```js
System
ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

I should add that `window.upgradeSystemLoader` is present, which is a function that is defined in the JavsScript library. So at least the file is being detected.

---

What is the difference? I am trying to serve System.js via bower from my own server, but I always end up in this situation: CDN works, local file doesn't.

Comment: Perhaps browser is prohibiting loading file from local filesystem?
Try Chrome's `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag

Comment: @DrewR, I also cannot get it to work when I serve it with IIS...

Comment: `@` is a reserved URL character ([ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#List_of_allowed_URL_characters)). So perhaps you have to encode it

Comment: I suspect it's treating the `@` as part of an [attempt to authenticate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basic_access_authentication).  When it's buried further along the url as per the CDN, it seems it's ok, but nearer the start it's being parsed as auth info.

Comment: It also doesn't work if I rename the file to just ``system.js``. I am following the angular 2 quick start from [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html), btw (scroll down to step 7).

Comment: @NikontheThird, I would check headers maybe for your local file if anything is blocking it.. inspector->network, peek there

Comment: Something is missing `es6-module-loader@0.16.6.js ` i think systemJs helps you load that js file. If you check your console. you would find that that es6-module is missing.

In the system file it requires this `src="'+basePath+'es6-module-loader@0.16.6.js`

You could download it here [es6-modules](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/releases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is missing `es6-module-loader@0.16.6.js` i think systemJs helps you load that js file. If you check your console. you would find that that es6-module is missing.

In the system file it requires this `src="'+basePath+'es6-module-loader@0.16.6.js`

You can either download it or change the path in the systemJs source file

You could download it here [es6-modules](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/releases)